# Matching BlowfishJ Java implementation to dren blowfish javascript implementation; encryption values after 8-bytes are different

Tags: java, javascript, algorithm, encryption, blowfish

I'm having some issues with correlating the BlowsfishJ Java implementation ([BlowfishJ Javadoc](http://blowfishj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/blowfishj/package-summary.html)) to the dren Blowfish JavaScript implementation ([dren Blowfish page](http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/)).

On the Java side, I'm using Blowfish CBC, with a zero IV and the key is *somekey*.  The plaintext is *WillThisEQ*.

On the JavaScript side, I PRESUME dren's implementation is using CBC and a zero IV, as well.  The key is *somekey* and the plaintext is *WillThisEQ*, as well.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var bf = new Blowfish('some key');
var ciphertext = bf.encrypt('WillThisEQ');
var plaintext = bf.decrypt(ciphertext);
```

For the ciphertext, The first 8-bytes match for both implementations (*WillThis*).  However, any subsequent bytes do NOT match (*EQ000000*).  The IV is factored into the first block ([Block Cipher Modes Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation)).  So, I don't think that's the problem.

How can I these two implementations to match?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is at the very top of the [dren BlowFish page you linked to](http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/):

> You need to impliment your own cipher-block chaining if you want to encrypt anything longer than 8 bytes.

So no, it's not doing CBC. You could try the [ECB version of BlowfishJ](http://blowfishj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/blowfishj/BlowfishECB.html), but [the security is much worse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).

Comment: Thank you very much. +1 for reading comprehension.  So, I'd have to write my own CBC for JS.  That must be why his implementation is encouraged to not be used for anything serious.  Would the ECB version of BlowfishJ work with his implementation?

Comment: @user717236 The page isn't clear about whether they'd work together,  but it's worth a try though. It looks like CBC isn't really that complicated, you just need to set the IV to a special value for each block.

Comment: Yeah, I'd have to write my own CBC.  I have confirmed the ECB version is not the same.  The JS implementation is encrypting the first 8-byte block only and is NOT using ECB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Dojo version of Blowfish. Works for me.
http://sladex.org/blowfish.js/